# SyntaxError: unexpected end of input discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I was making a discord bot. Here is the code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!";


client.on("message", function(message) { 
if (message.author.bot) return;  
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  
const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
const args = commandBody.split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
if (command === "help") {
message.reply(`Discord Revolution
Upon hitting Ctrl + / to bring up the Discord Key Combos menu, four directional arrows will appear in the upper-right-hand corner of the dialog. Pressing the arrows on your keyboard will play a designated tone for each direction. You can press multiple keys at a time to create chords.

Error Page
If you get to the discord 404 ERROR page and press the button to the right of the hamster or enter in the Konami code, you can play "SNEK". SNEK is essentially the classic Snake.

Copied Username
When you click on your profile number/ID, Discord copies it for you and displays a little green text box with "Copied!" in it.

Discord_Name_Copy_Easter_Egg
Discord Name Copy Easter Egg

Repeatedly clicking your ID will prompt the following messages:

Copied!
Double Copy!
Triple Copy!
Dominating!!
Rampage!!
Mega Copy!!
Unstoppable!!
Wicked Sick!!
Monster Copy!!!
GODLIKE!!!!
BEYOND GODLIKE!!!!
Note: 'GODLIKE!!!' and 'BEYOND GODLIKE!!!!' have a shaking text box with a red background.

This is a reference to kill streaks in Dota 2, where each of these lines is played in succession after each kill, and then stopping at BEYOND GODLIKE!!!! and repeating it until the streak ends.

New_Discord_Ringtone
New Discord Ringtone`)
}
require('http').createServer((_, res) => res.end("Nothing here! This is for a discord bot. Join My discord server: https://discord.com/invite/SrGJhjbqaY")).listen(8080)
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Then I got this error when I run it
**
/home/runner/DiscordEasterEggs/index.js:52
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
**

How to fix this?

Comment: It expects a `}` at the end

Comment: But I got another error. 
```
}
^

SyntaxError: Missing after argument list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', function (message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'help') {
    message.reply(`Discord Revolution
Upon hitting Ctrl + / to bring up the Discord Key Combos menu, four directional arrows will appear in the upper-right-hand corner of the dialog. Pressing the arrows on your keyboard will play a designated tone for each direction. You can press multiple keys at a time to create chords.

Error Page
If you get to the discord 404 ERROR page and press the button to the right of the hamster or enter in the Konami code, you can play "SNEK". SNEK is essentially the classic Snake.

Copied Username
When you click on your profile number/ID, Discord copies it for you and displays a little green text box with "Copied!" in it.

Discord_Name_Copy_Easter_Egg
Discord Name Copy Easter Egg

Repeatedly clicking your ID will prompt the following messages:

Copied!
Double Copy!
Triple Copy!
Dominating!!
Rampage!!
Mega Copy!!
Unstoppable!!
Wicked Sick!!
Monster Copy!!!
GODLIKE!!!!
BEYOND GODLIKE!!!!
Note: 'GODLIKE!!!' and 'BEYOND GODLIKE!!!!' have a shaking text box with a red background.

This is a reference to kill streaks in Dota 2, where each of these lines is played in succession after each kill, and then stopping at BEYOND GODLIKE!!!! and repeating it until the streak ends.

New_Discord_Ringtone
New Discord Ringtone`);
  }
});
require('http')
  .createServer((_, res) =>
    res.end(
      'Nothing here! This is for a discord bot. Join My discord server: https://discord.com/invite/SrGJhjbqaY',
    ),
  )
  .listen(8080);
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

You were missing `})` at the line above that `require('http')` one

Comment: It fixed the SyntaxError. However, I got another error.